# Doubts about Jenkins Maven Integration Plugin behaviour

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins in a big project, to do **Continuous Integration** (CI) among other things. Our jobs are created as **Maven project**, so the executions launched by the CI are triggered by the **Maven Integration Plugin** (v2.17) included in our Jenkins installation (v1.652).

I have a couple of questions about the plugin behaviour:

1) When a Maven project is executed, sometimes in its log you can see this:

Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph

but ¿when is this triggered? ¿can it be forced?

2) Is there a limit number of jobs whose dependencies can be managed by the plugin? we have ~15000 jobs and I suspect that the mecanism in charge of setting the upstream jobs and downstream jobs has stopped working:

[image]

Can I force the update of the downstream/upstream projects?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First really 15000 jobs? Why do you have so many upstream/downstream dependencies? What kind of relationships are those? Are are really on that old version of Jenkins 1.652 which is not an LTS release so you are running on an very old weekly release...The parsing is done in cases where modules have been added/removed etc. this triggers this..no it can not being forced...

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds crazy, but we have a microservice architecture on a very big project, there are more than 500 people working on it, and we have a CI job for each trunk/branch that they are coding...
The relationships are maven dependencies, but a project may depends on 1-10 other projects, sometimes this number is higher but that's not the common case.
Do you mean maven modules? or entire new jobs?

Comment: I think you should think about multi branch pipelines which handles that for each project with the appropriate branches...which makes it easier..Apart from that If you have microservices than you shouldn't have Upstream/Downstream dependencies ?